# How to type my code? (Property 'item' does not exist on type 'object')

Tags: typescript

Hi everyone please help me
when trying to find a value in my array of objects, I get an error

**Property 'item' does not exist on type 'object'**

in line **el => el.item**

how can i fix this

```
const heroArray = useAppSelector((state) => state.heroList.items)

 const addHero = (item:string, index:number):void => {
    const elements = {
      id,
      item
    }
    dispatch(addItem(elements))
    const b = heroArray.find(el => el.item === 'geovishap-hatchling')
  }
```

types/ redux toolkit slice

```
interface HeroList {
  items: object[];
  elements: {
    id: string | undefined;
    item: string;
  }
}

const initialState: HeroList = {
  items: [],
  elements: {
    id:'',
    item:'',
  }
}

export const heroListSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'heroList',
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    addItem: (state, action: PayloadAction<Object>) => {
      state.items.push(action.payload)
      localStorage.setItem('items', JSON.stringify(state.items));
    },
  },
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your interface where you have 'element': {...} make element: SomeInterface. Create another interface that defines that for the element structure.

```
{
    id:string,
    item:string
}
```

Something like this

```
interface HeroListElements {
  id: string; // I would drop this -> | undefined
  item: string;
}

interface HeroList {
  items: object[]; // <- I would not use object
  elements: HeroListElements
}

const initialState: HeroList = {
  items: [],
  elements: {
    id: '',
    item: ''
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you mean add this to the heroList interface?

Comment: @Ijuy23kl see update

Answer (score 0):

Do not use `object` for objects. `object` in TS means object-like element

```
const f: object = [];
```

In your case you need to define type `Hero` and use it instead of `object`

```
type Hero = {
  id: string,
  item: string
}

interface HeroList {
  items: Hero[];
  elements: {
    id: string | undefined;
    item: string;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change line

```
const elements = {
  id,
  item
}
```

by

```
const elements = {
      id:index,
      item
    }
```

cause you are refering id by index in the function argument